# kotlin unresolved KDoc link but IntelliJ doesn't like the import that fixes it

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

```
import abc.MyClass.MyEnum; /// from Java

/**
 * [MyClass.MyEnum]
 */
class efg () : MyClass.MyEnum {
    return MyClass.MyEnum.BiGNUMBER;
}
```

I have something similar to the above in IntelliJ... but it will identify the import as *unused* - so optimize imports will remove it... however, if I don't insert that import manually then in my docs it will identify [MyClass.MyEnum] as *cannot be resolved*

What can I do?

Comment: is there a way to mark an import not to be removed?

Comment: You should add an Issue to the Dokka project, https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka about this.  Maybe also one to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com referencing that one.  I'm not sure who will want to fix it, from the perspective of Dokka or the Kotlin IDE plugin.

Comment: This is fixed as of 2019

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10398) in the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this issue